# I want to search between two dates in sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables and this table name is "rooms" [image: Table Rooms] and other one is "bookings" [image: !Table Bookings]

I joined two tables now, I want values when i will search between

`book_form = "2016-12-30"` and `book_to = "2016-12-31"`

it will be return true because this two dates does not exists in the "bookings" table, and when search between

`book_form = "2016-12-30"` and `book_to = "2017-01-05"` 
or `book_form = "2017-01-03"` and `book_to = "2017-01-15"`

it will be return false because this date exists in bookings table.

This is my query.

```
select * from rooms join room_book on rooms.room_id = room_book.room_id 
where status = 'available' and room_book.book_from NOT BETWEEN '2016-12-30' 
AND room_book.book_to NOT BETWEEN '2016-12-31'
```

Comment: You consistently mention a column called book_fORm. Do you mean book_fROm?

Comment: And see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Kishan Patel returns all records between two dates. So if you want a true or false if a room is available between two dates, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, TRUE, FALSE) AS NewResult
from rooms 
join room_book on rooms.room_id = room_book.room_id
where status = 'available' 
and room_book.book_from >= '2016-12-30' AND room_book.book_to <= '2016-12-31'
```

Comment: right my query return records if room booked in between date so return empty result means no any booking available between two date.

Comment: Yes you can simply throw custom error or else use count function instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this one return all record between two dates

```
select * from rooms 
join room_book on rooms.room_id = room_book.room_id
where status = 'available' 
and room_book.book_from >= '2016-12-30' AND room_book.book_to <= '2016-12-31'
```

make sure its useful to you

Comment: your query not returned anything.

Comment: return empty results.

Comment: This is back to front.